# Display array sorted based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
Array 1 : $agents = Array('abc','xyz','pqr');
Array 2 : $tot_calls = Array ('10','5','20');
```

Here array 2 reflects total calls made by agents in $agents array respectively.
i.e Agent abc made 10 calls , Agent xyz made 5 calls and so on.

I want the resultant array to display agents sorted(DESCENDING) by the number of calls they made

i.e `$result = Array('pqr','abc','xyz');` // Here the resulting array is sorted on the max calls they made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `array_combine()` the `krsort()` on this particular situation. Consider this example:

```
$agents = Array('abc','xyz','pqr');
$tot_calls = Array ('10','5','20');
// calls become the keys and agents become the values
$sorted_values = array_combine($tot_calls, $agents);
krsort($sorted_values); // sort them by keys

print_r($sorted_values);

// maybe if you want to clear the keys
$sorted_values = array_values($sorted_values);
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hmhC3d)

EDIT:

Alternatively, @Satish made a good point about it. To avoid the same key issue (well maybe, at least if there are no agent name collision). You can use this instead (just the other way around):

```
$agents = Array('abc','xyz','pqr');
$tot_calls = Array ('10','5','20');
// agents become keys and calls become values
$sorted_values = array_combine($agents, $tot_calls);
arsort($sorted_values);
$sorted_values = array_keys($sorted_values);

print_r($sorted_values);
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/g4hRRo)

Comment: its wrong method what will happen if there is more users with same calls how will the same index in your array by array_combine.

Comment: what will happen if there is one more user with same calls like `$agents = Array('abc','xyz','pqr', 'lmn');
$tot_calls = Array ('10','5','20','5');`

Comment: @kevinabelita not right yet. see [link](http://codepad.org/HlG9ZloX) of your code

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$agents = Array('abc','xyz','pqr');
$tot_calls = Array (10, 5, 20);

arsort($tot_calls);
foreach($tot_calls as $key=>$val)
{
  $arr_agents[] = $agents[$key];
}
print_r($arr_agents);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => pqr
    [1] => abc
    [2] => xyz
)
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/qNfdmNNF)**

**[DEMO-2](http://codepad.org/CyWQnyup) :** with

```
$agents = Array('abc','xyz','pqr','lmn');
$tot_calls = Array ('10', '5', '20', '5');
```

**OUTPUT-2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => pqr
    [1] => abc
    [2] => lmn
    [3] => xyz
)
```